# How does the QTR-8RC capacitor charging works?

Tags: sensor, capacitor

I would like to understand how does work the polulu Reflectance Sensor internally. I can make it work but I would like to know what is happening electrically.

http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/961

This is the schema (focus on the bottom left part, the squared area).

http://a.pololu-files.com/picture/0J629.650.png?7975fd7128a0eb0861e253d9c7f439c0

An these are the steps to read a value:

1. Turn on IR LEDs (optional)
2. Set the I/O line to an output and drive it high
3. Allow at least 10 us for the 10 nF capacitor to charge
4. Make the I/O line an input (high impedance)
5. Measure the time for the capacitor to discharge by waiting for the
   I/O line to go low
6. Turn off IR LEDs (optional)

I guess initially the 10 nF capacitor is charged. Why does it say in step 3 to charge it again. Do you charge "the other side" of the capacitor?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third pint should read

> Allow at least 10 us for the 10 nF capacitor to *discharge*.

If the capacitor has Vcc on both sides it's discharged. (IR) light on the phototransistor will cause a current to ground, so that voltage builds up on the capacitor, making its lower side go lower, as the other side is fixed at Vcc. Since the charging is through a current source instead of a resistor the voltage will decrease linearly with time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why is that "If the capacitor has Vcc on both sides it's discharged". Where does the energy...go?

Related with: "Since the charging is through a current source instead of a resistor the voltage will decrease linearly with time" 

This linear decreasing still depends on the phototransistor value, right?

Comment: If it's charged the voltage on the lower pin is 0 V or near it. In step 2 you make the I/O output high, then there's current from the output through the resistor to the lower pin, so that the voltage increases. Charge is voltage x capacitance, so as the voltage across the cap decreases, the charge decreases. And yes, the linear decreasing depends on the phototransistor. The more light it gets the faster the decrease.